# Docker and Rancher - Run multiple workers

Tags: asynchronous, docker, command, containers, rancher

I need to run 3 commands to run my application:

```
$ celery -A name worker
$ daphne name.asgi:channel_layer -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000
$ python manage.py runworker
```

I need to do this for the same image, I do not know if it is viable to create a container for each command. What should I do?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that they are all services, there must be a container for each one.